# Why am I getting "No provider for ReducerManager!" error on unit tests for lazy loaded Angular 6 app with ngrx?

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular6, ngrx

I have a **lazy loading** Angular 6 app that uses **ngrx**.  I have an:

```
app.module.ts
shared.module.ts
core.module.ts
```

The core module has things like the footer and header.  There are no store/ngrx related stuff here, but the unit tests for the header (that were working before implementing ngrx) keep failing with the following error:

`StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StoreFeatureModule -> ReducerManager]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ReducerManager!`

The only thing I can think of is that the `StoreModule` is not imported into the `CoreModule`.  But should it?  Why are the tests failing when the header has nothing to do with state?

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
        maxAge: 5   // retains last 5 states
    }) : []
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```

})

**core.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent, 
        FooterComponent, 
    ]
})
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        MyComponent
    ],
    declarations: [ MyComponent]
})
export class SharedModule {
```

** header.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
    let component: HeaderComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;
    let debugEl: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ 
                ProductsModule,
                CustomersModule
        ],
        declarations: [ HeaderComponent ],
        providers: [
            { provide: myService, useValue: new MyService() },
        ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugEl = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the code in your header component tests that is setting up your test module?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel, edited my question to include the spec file

Comment: Note: the ProductsModule and CustomersModule do utilize the `Store` via ngrx

Comment: Ok, so that will be your problem. Your tests are using modules that use the service in question. You'll probably want to mock that service out in your tests (best probably to make use of spies on the actual service instance) or you can not import those modules and mock out anything around them in your tests. It really depends on how much you are testing. Are these tests meant to be unit or integration tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your component uses the NgRx store, you also have to import the store inside the `TestBed`.

Comment: pay attention - not the Store class -he need  the StoreModule

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

describe('test:', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
    HeldMessagesTabsPageModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(
      {
        messagesRoot: combineReducers(reducers.reducers)
      },
      {
        initialState: { messagesRoot: { messagesRoot: { template: templateInitialState } } }
      }
    )
  ],

  const store: Store<reducers.State>;
}

beforeEach(() => {
  store = TestBed.get(Store);
  spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();
});
```